# WordPress home page duplicate content issue. Need a resolution to avoid Google smack

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress blog has a single post designated as sticky that will always load when the `site.com` address is hit.

However, since this is a post it resolves to both `insert-post-name-here` and `index.php` in my *sitemap*.

For example, the link to `Home` and the link to the `insert-post-name-here` page appear to be two different pages for Google, but they load the exact same content.

This creates a potential duplicate content penalty with the `Big G`.

Any suggestions how to work around this?

Comment: There is no duplicate content penalty: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html

Having two instances of a single page isn't anything to worry about, *especially* if only one of those pages is actually linked to.

If you're really that worried about it, throw an exclude in robots.txt for the second URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Permalink Redirect WordPress Plugin](http://scott.yang.id.au/code/permalink-redirect/), or hard code the sticky content in index.php (or a template file based on index.php) so it's always there.